# I INSTALLED THE OS BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO CHANGE FROM WINDOWS TO ELEMENTARY

Tags: system-installation

I installed elementary os, but I don't know how to go from windows to elementary, and in the list of systems it doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by that exactly? Is elementary invisible in your BIOS? What happens if you select the partition that you installed it on?

If it just stays that way check if you have FastBoot enabled and Legacy Boot disabled. However I would require more detailed information for further assistance.